# Porque en mi sitio web algunos fa fa-icons dejaron de verse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenos dias a todos, el dia de hoy tengo una pregunta bastante intrigante. Les comento tengo un sitio web en produccion, que hasta hace no mucho funcionaba genial y ahora dejaron de verse 2 fafa icons el resto si se ven pero esos dos ya no. Y como yo me dedico al backend simplemente compro las plantillas, las modifico y les pongo todo el backend, asi que mucho de css y html no entiendo. Alguien sabe a que se puede deber? Si necesitan alguna otra parte del codigo pidanmela.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                <b class="caret"> </b>
                               <?php if($numero > 0){ ?><span class="notification"><?php echo $numero; ?></span> <?php } ?>
                          </a>
```

Ese el fa fa-globe es uno de los que ya no se ven.

Comment: Yo no sé mucho de "fafa icons", pero si lo que has heho comprar la plantilla, ¿has probado a preguntar al que te la vendió?
Si pudieras compartir un enlace donde funcione un fafa icon y otro donde no funcione, puedo analizarte el código y buscar diferencias o problemas... Pero así, con código a medias, poco puedo hacer. Un link a una página en el navegador sería interesante. Si no, habría que buscar los archivos css donde están las clases de los fafaicons

Comment: Hola Santiago, podrias poner un ejemplo de codigo donde funcione tu fa fa-icon

Comment: Además, por lo que dices, tiene pinta de que el icono esté ubicado en un sitio web externo, y ya no está disponible

Comment: newclan.com.uy/cuenta

User: Demo_Demo
Pass: demo123

Veran que en la parte superior izquierda hay una flechita para abajo que muestra las notificaciones pero no aparece el globo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que veo es que estas incluyendo la hoja de estilo de `FontAwesome` y la fuente `Roboto de Google Fonts` usando el protocolo `HTTP` cuando tu sitio es cargado usando `HTTPS`, por lo que el navegador para asegurar la seguridad de la conexión simplemente los rechaza (*no los carga*).

Al usar el [`protocolo seguro de transferencia de hipertexto (HTTPS)`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol_Secure) se espera que todos los links a recursos externos **también sean seguros**, de lo contrario no se podría asegurar que se esta trabajando de forma segura.

En resumen, modifica esto:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Y hazlo así (*sin indicar el protocolo*):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Eso era exactamente, muchas gracias colega. Por eso dejo de funcionar hace poco, porque hace apenas unos dias le puse SSL

Answer (score 0):

A no ser que se lo estés indicando en otro sitio y tengas la hoja de estilos en el servidor, tal y como ha comentado Sergio Peris parece que el icono está ubicado en una web externa y el enlace a esa web externa que estás indicando es este: **#**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
```

Fijate en este ejemplo donde no es una web externa, si no un directorio (font-awesome-4.7.0/css/) del propio servidor y le indica la ubicación del archivo de estilos para los iconos *.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

en el caso de ser un sitio externo sería así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Te recomiendo que el archivo de estilos lo alojes en tu servidor por si el servidor/página externa del que se obtienen no está disponible no te desaparezcan los iconos.

P.D: si ese archivo *css de estilos para los iconos lo tienes ya en tu servidor solo tienes que indicarle la ruta como en el primer ejemplo pero con tus directorios claro.